# How to measure real size a object by using the other object ( square marker ) when knowing the real size in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

I have to make a mobile app that calculates the real size of an object in a binary image, use another object ( square marker) when I know real size.

How I can measure real object with knowing real size another object in a binary image? In MATLAB we can using function `regionprops`, how to do it in Android? do i have to detect the first square region ? and calculating  value 1 pixel more or no other way?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by, "How I can measure real object with knowing real size another object in a binary?". Also, you mention that you can use `regionprops` to do the same task. Can you give an example using `regionprops`. Probably that will explain your question.

Comment: The above link is not an exact duplicate, but it's enough to get you started.  Especially take a look at point #1 in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not explain it well.  I have a problem when making the program calculate the real size a object .
When the acquisition of images , object is placed in horizontal with square object 1 cm x 1cm. I processing that image  into a black and white image, so remaining region square and region object to be counted the measure real size. in matlab we using regionprops to measure area of selected region of an image in pixel count. How to do it in android?